# What does "bearing about in the body the dying of the Lord Jesus" mean in 2 Corinthians 4:10?

Tags: greek, word-study, romans, pneumatology, cross

What does

**"bearing about in the body the dying of the Lord Jesus"**

mean in

2 Corinthians 4:10 always bearing about in the body the dying of the Lord Jesus, that the life also of Jesus might be made manifest in our body.

?

What experience is it talking about?

and

How to experience it?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Persecution - Open Doors]

Ask any of 300 million or more Christians who suffer systematic oppression, deprivation, harm every day for the privilege of bearing the name "Christ-ian"

> 2 Corinthians 11:22-30. "far greater labors, far more imprisonments, with countless beatings, and often near death. 24 Five times I received at the hands of the Jews the forty lashes less one. 25 Three times I was beaten with rods. Once I was stoned. Three times I was shipwrecked; a night and a day I was adrift at sea; 26 on frequent journeys, in danger from rivers, danger from robbers, danger from my own people, danger from Gentiles, danger in the city, danger in the wilderness, danger at sea, danger from false brothers; 27 in toil and hardship, through many a sleepless night, in hunger and thirst, often without food,[b] in cold and exposure."
>
> 1 Peter 4:1 "Since therefore Christ suffered in the flesh, arm yourselves with the same purpose, for whoever has suffered in the flesh has ceased from sin, so as to live for the rest of the time in the flesh no longer for human passions but for the will of God."

My position is that the power of the living Christ (through the Holy Spirit in the body) works effectively through "dead" vessels - dead to the stimulus of the world/flesh/devils. I take Romans 8:13 and related supporting verses quite seriously - that followers of Christ are marked by separation from what I call the "false fuel of Flesh", and switch-over our tanks to running on "by the Spirit" energy.  It is a long discussion and a longer walk, but the only way an American, I think, can get a taste of it is by devoting large chunks of time, habitually, to the Lord alone, "practicing righteousness" and begging for the "Granting" of true repentance. It does not come by accident. The path is shortened considerably by capture, torture, the loss of all worldly means, etc via persecution, war, famine, etc.

The GOOD NEWS, unless one is a [cessationist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessationism), is that the Holy Spirit will intensely work in such people, channeling through them the proof of Christ's living presence. The most alarming, arresting proof, (though certainly not the Only) is radically changed lives, lived on a long walk unto death. That is a work of the spirit, not mental.

Answer (score 1):

Paul is speaking only about the apostles; sharing the experience is not what he is suggesting. The "we" here is the apostles and the "you" are the Corinthians:

> [2Co 4:7-12 ESV] (7) But **we** have this treasure in jars of clay, to show that the surpassing power belongs to God and not to **us**. (8) **We** are afflicted in every way, but not crushed; perplexed, but not driven to despair; (9) persecuted, but not forsaken; struck down, but not destroyed; (10) always carrying in the body the death of Jesus, so that the life of Jesus may also be manifested in our bodies. (11) For **we** [IE: we apostles] who live [IE: "are still alive"] are always being given over to death for Jesus' sake, so that the life of Jesus also may be manifested in **our** mortal flesh. (12) **So death is at work in **us**, but life in **you**.**
>
> [Col 1:24 ESV] (24) Now I rejoice in my sufferings for your sake, and in my flesh I am filling up what is lacking in Christ's afflictions for the sake of his body, that is, the church,

Answer (score 1):

Taken in context, the NT words “carrying in the body the death of Jesus” may be reference to the actual persecution that Paul and other Christians were suffering, which he himself once perpetrated, as a result of giving witness to Jesus’s life:

- You have heard, no doubt, of my earlier life in Judaism. I was violently persecuting the church of God and was trying to destroy it. (Gal 1:13)
- Are they ministers of Christ? I am talking like a madman—*I am a better one*: with far greater labors, far more imprisonments, with countless floggings, and often near death. Five times I have received… forty lashes minus one. Three times I was beaten with rods. Once I received a stoning… in toil and hardship, through many a sleepless night, hungry and thirsty, often without food, cold and naked. (2 Cor 11:23-25)

Paul experienced hardship and persecution, but he argued that his sufferings made him a better minister for Christ. Christians believe that Christ died for the salvation of souls. In saying that he carried Jesus’ death in his body, Paul seemed to suggest that the physical suffering he and others endured, when joined to the sacrifice of Jesus, was a way of advancing the work of salvation:

- I am now rejoicing in my sufferings *for your sake*, and in my flesh I am completing what is lacking in Christ’s afflictions for the sake of his body, that is, the church. (Col 1:24)
- But even if I am being poured out as a libation over the sacrifice and the offering of your faith, I am glad and rejoice with all of you (Phil 2:17)
- So death is at work in us, but life in you. (2 Rom 4:12)

Answer (score 0):

To be a Christian is to be persecuted daily for our beliefs (1 Corinthians 15:30-31), but His spiritual life is manifest in our mortal life, trusting in His forgiveness, His ruler ship, even His real presence in our mortal bodies, the Church (1 Corinthians 10:16-17), for He is the bread of life.

Comment: If you take a careful look at 1 Cor 15:30-31, doesn't Paul only refer to himself and the other apostles, not to the Corinthians? And what does 1 Cor 10:16-17 say about "real presence" or "bearing about in the body the dying of the Lord Jesus"? Do you mean carrying around bread? Also, can you please cite the verses rather than just providing the addresses? Thanks.  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding this verse is through contrast as a literary device.

2 Corinthians 4:10
New International Version

> We always carry around in our body the **death** of Jesus, so that the **life** of Jesus may also be revealed in our body.

Here in one verse, we have the contrast between the death and life of Jesus in our body. This is the theme of the whole chapter.

> 7 But we have this treasure in jars of clay to show that this all-surpassing power is from God and not from us.

Introduce jars of clay as a symbol for our frail bodies.

> 8 We are hard pressed on every side, but not crushed; perplexed, but not in despair; 9 persecuted, but not abandoned; struck down, but not destroyed.

These are examples of sufferings of Jesus or death of Jesus. Paul carried or experienced these in his body.

> 11 For we who are alive are always being given over to **death** for Jesus’ sake, so that his **life** may also be revealed in our mortal body.

Again the bad news/good news contrast.

> 12 So then, **death** is at work in us, but **life** is at work in you.

> 16 Therefore we do not lose heart. Though outwardly we are **wasting** away, yet inwardly we are being **renewed** day by day.

Finally,

> 18 So we fix our eyes not on what is **seen**, but on what is **unseen**, since what is seen is **temporary**, but what is unseen is **eternal**.

The whole chapter is filled with contrasts between death and life of Jesus, ie, the outward seen sufferings vs the inward unseen glory in our body.

How to experience it?

It's a daily affair as we yield our body to obey God.

Matthew 16:24

> Then Jesus said to his disciples, "Whoever wants to be my disciple must deny themselves and take up their cross and follow me.

Answer (score -1):

"bearing about in the body the dying of the Lord Jesus"

When I read this passage of scripture it means so much more to me than the things that I have suffered or endured over the past fifty years. It speaks to me of the reality of what it means to embrace His passion and purpose in the way we lay down our lives for one another. It also reminds us that we are dead, buried and resurrected in HIM. We have been bought with a price and our life is not our own. Selah!

Comment: Hi Blake, welcome to BHSE! Please take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance. This answer doesn't demonstrate any engagement with the text or any 'digging' in other passages. Please take a look around other Questions and Answers on the site and consider Editing this post to improve the quality of the post. Have a great day.

Answer (score -2):

in baptism into Christ - into His death and into His life - into His resurrection 
by Holy spirit - the Holy Spirit will lead one into it if one had received Him

one can know it - if he in mortality of Jesus - if he has nothing to do  with sin anymore and does not fear the death

you are dead like Christ if you have no reaction on temptation and threat of death

Comment: Hello and welcome. When you have a minute please take the site tour:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour